# CakePHP routes regular expression for unicode

Tags: regex, cakephp, unicode, routes

I want to do the following change in CakePHP routes. Any word or group of words (separated by hyphen) after a website URL like `example.com/someword` or `example.com/some-word` should be redirected to `controller => posts, action => view`. But my problem is that the word(s) should be in unicode. I have tried this regular expression for URL text, but it does not work.

> Router::connect ( '/:link', array ('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view' ), array ('pass' => array ('link'), 'link' => '/^['.json_decode('"\u0531"').'-'.json_decode('"\u0587"').'-]+$/u' ) );

I want to mention though, that my regex

```
'/^['.json_decode('"\u0531"').'-'.json_decode('"\u0587"').'-]+$/u',
```

works just fine if I am about to do some usual preg_match like

```
$regg = '/^['.json_decode('"\u0531"').'-'.json_decode('"\u0587"').'-]+$/u';
if (preg_match($regg, "my unicode string", $match)) {
  var_dump($match);   // outputs string as expected
}
die;
```

**EDIT**

I end up having this code

```
Router::connect ( '/:link', array ('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view' ), array    ('pass' => array ('link'), 'link' => '((?![a-zA-Z]).)+' ) );
```

like making my url to contain everything, but English letters, but this is not the thing I need, if I have 2 or more different languages than English - this method won't work. So, I want to send each language's word into separate action.

cake version 2.x

**EDIT 2**

There are alternative solutions, like in answers below, to bypass the question, but I am looking for the exact way of doing what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string at *URL encoding* paragraph you can't use these chars on a url query string:

> In particular, encoding the query string uses the following rules:
>
> - Letters (A–Z and a–z), numbers (0–9) and the characters '.','-','~' and '_' are left as-is
> - SPACE is encoded as '+' or "%20" [8]
> - All other characters are encoded as %HH hex representation with any non-ASCII characters first encoded as UTF-8 (or other specified
>     encoding)

If you have two (or more) languages you can consider add on posts table one slug field for each language, for example with english and russian:

posts

- id
- title_eng
- title_rus
- slug_eng
- slug_rus

On Post.php beforeValidate or beforeSave:

```
if(isset($this->data['Post']['title_eng'])){
    $this->data['Post']['slug_eng'] = Inflector::slug(strtolower($this->data['Post']['title_eng']), '-');
}
if(isset($this->data['Post']['title_rus'])){
    $this->data['Post']['slug_rus'] = Inflector::slug(strtolower($this->data['Post']['title_rus']), '-');
}
```

The link inside a view:

```
echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title_eng'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'slug_eng' => $post['Post']['slug_eng']));
echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title_rus'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'slug_rus' => $post['Post']['slug_rus']));
```

The route:

```
Router::connect('/posts/:slug_eng', array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'view', 'eng'), array('pass' => array('slug_eng'), 'slug_eng' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/ru/posts/:slug_rus', array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'view', 'rus'), array('pass' => array('slug_rus'), 'slug_rus' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+'));
```

The controller Posts:

```
public function view($locale, $slug){
    ....
    validate and sanitize here
    ...
    $post = $this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => array('slug_' . $locale => $slug)));
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, see, u r rigth other chars r being encoding to hex, but any case how to write the regex(and especially in cake) for it to work in cake, that is the question. The alternative solution looks ok, but it is not what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use wildcard

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'));
```

Any other routes can be added before this line, for example

```
Router::connect('/:digits', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('digits'), 'digits' => '/d+');
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'));
```

Comment: THanks for the answer, it is an alternative again, but not what I need. THanks